# A quick way to screen a data frame contents over multiple weeks

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have a data frame, the contents of which change partially weekly.

Imagine that I own a car showroom, and after each week I may have sold some cars and acquired others for sale. My task is to figure out average time to sale of the cars weekly. Although in my example the weekly dataframes are of the same length, this is not necessarily the case in that I may have bought more cars than I sold or vice versa.

Consider these 4 data frames:

```
serial_no <- c('A1','B2','C3','D4','E5','F6')
brand <- c('Mercedes','BMW','Audi','Jaguar','Nissan','Volkswagen')
model <- c('S-class','5-series','Q8','XF','GT-R','Eos')
df.week1 <- data.frame(serial_no,brand,model)

serial_no2 <- c('B2','C3','D4','E5','F6','G7')
brand2 <- c('BMW','Audi','Jaguar','Nissan','Volkswagen','Mercedes')
model2 <- c('5-series','Q8','XF','GT-R','Eos','E-class')
df.week2 <- data.frame(serial_no2,brand2,model2)

serial_no3 <- c('B2','D4','E5','F6','G7','H8')
brand3 <- c('BMW','Jaguar','Nissan','Volkswagen','Mercedes','BMW')
model3 <- c('5-series','XF','GT-R','Eos','E-class','5-series')
df.week3 <- data.frame(serial_no3,brand3,model3)

serial_no4 <- c('D4','F6','G7','I9','J10','K11')
brand4 <- c('Jaguar','Volkswagen','Mercedes','BMW','Toyota','Lexus')
model4 <- c('XF','Eos','E-class','7-series','Corolla','RC')
df.week4 <- data.frame(serial_no4,brand4,model4)

#to tidy up

library(plyr)
df.week2 <- rename(df.week2,c('serial_no2' = 'serial_no','brand2'='brand','model2'='model'))
df.week3 <- rename(df.week3,c('serial_no3' = 'serial_no','brand3'='brand','model3'='model'))
df.week4 <- rename(df.week4,c('serial_no4' = 'serial_no','brand4'='brand','model4'='model'))
```

Now I can pretty simply tell which cars I have sold in the last week, for example by:

```
library(dplyr)
in3not4 <- anti_join(df.week3,df.week4,by='serial_no')
```

However, the second part of my task is to find when they came into the showroom in the first place. Obviously one could achieve this by doing multiple anti_join techniques, but with very many weeks and very many thousands of rows to analyze, this soon becomes a mind-boggling task.

My question, then, is if there is an easier way to perform this task? I need to find out:

A) when the sold cars first appeared in the showroom

B) what the average time to sale is for all cars sold in a given week (NB my df 'in3not4' shows all cars sold between the start of week 3 and the start of week 4)

I have to think there is a simple tool for this task. Appreciative of any help.

Comment: what does the data-format look like in reality? (seperate csv-files,...); given your data-format above, I would add a column week with a number for the week of the data and just rbind all of the data-frames together, then I would do something like: `library(data.table); setDT(df)[ , .N, by = serial_no][N > 1, serial_no] -> sold_cars_serials; df[ serial_no %in% sold_cars_serials, min(week), by = serial_no]` to get when the sold cars first appeared in the showroom, the second question would be: `df[ serial_no %in% sold_cars_serials, max(week) - min(week), by = serial_no]`

Comment: If you add a row week (constant 1 for df.week1 and so on), you can take min(week) for a certain car for question A and max(week)-min(week) for question B

Comment: I forgot that you would have to do `max(week) - min(week) + 1` since the car got sold one week after the week it last appeared in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand clearly how you'd like the output to look like. But here's an attempt using `data.table v1.9.5` - installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation):

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
m.dt = rbindlist(list(df.week1, df.week2, df.week3, df.week4), idcol = "week")
max_week = max(m.dt$week)
ans = m.dt[, .(week_in  = week[1L], 
               week_out = ifelse(max_week == week[.N], NA_integer_, week[.N])), 
          by=.(serial_no, brand, model)]
#     serial_no      brand    model week_in week_out
#  1:        A1   Mercedes  S-class       1        1
#  2:        B2        BMW 5-series       1        3
#  3:        C3       Audi       Q8       1        2
#  4:        D4     Jaguar       XF       1       NA
#  5:        E5     Nissan     GT-R       1        3
#  6:        F6 Volkswagen      Eos       1       NA
#  7:        G7   Mercedes  E-class       2       NA
#  8:        H8        BMW 5-series       3        3
#  9:        I9        BMW 7-series       4       NA
# 10:       J10     Toyota  Corolla       4       NA
# 11:       K11      Lexus       RC       4       NA
```

The idea should be clear (assuming I've understood the task correctly). I'll leave the rest to you to get it in the form you'd like..

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. However, sitting inside a corporate environment as I do, using devtools/github is simply not feasible. Do you have any timeframe for the release of x1.9.5 on CRAN at this stage? Many thanks